# SSRS Hide Duplicate and hiding white space

Tags: reporting-services

When I hide the duplicate it leaves an extra blank line. I have tried to adjust the spacing and I can not figure out how to hide the white space.

Here is what it looks like now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2nOK.png

Would like to to be close together on the next line down.

Comment: Is the visibility set on the textbox or the row itself?  If you set it to hide on the row itself, you should get the desired results.

Comment: It is still leaving a white space

Comment: Can you set the `CanGrow` property to false and the `CanShrink` to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to diagnose whitespace issues is to put borders around everything. This will make apparent what section might be causing extra space.

If it is truly being caused by the hide duplicate property, ensure you have put the property on the correct section as @Steve-o169 commented. Hidden properties are always best place on the row to ensure the row gets suppressed.

INSTEAD of the HideDuplicates, If you have double checked everything else, try this in the hidden expression for the details row (or whatever row section you are dealing with)

**Hidden Expression:**

```
=IIF(Previous(Fields!YourField.Value) = Fields!YourFields.Value, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my issue!